# Passing a Query String via .HTACCESS

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect

I have a dynamic query string that I need to pass via an .htaccess redirect. For example:

I need to redirect this URL: `http://mysite.com/page1?action=signup&var2=dynamicVar`

To this: `http://mysite.com?action=signup&var2=dynamicVar`

I know this is pretty simple, but I'm really not sure what type of rule/syntax would work for this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have .htaccess then simply add this line:

```
RewriteRule ^page1/?$ page2 [L,R,QSA,NC]
```

**Update:** Based on your comments:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)action=signup(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^page1/?$ / [L,R,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm trying to do.  However, I mis-spoke in my question.  I really need to redirect this: http://mysite.com/page1?var=dynamicVar

To this: http://mysite.com?var=dynamicVar    . Any idea on how could do that?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, however, I wasn't totally clear again (sorry!).  I've revised my original post above.  The big thing is that I only need to redirect if the first part of the query string matches 'action=signup'.

Comment: Ah the ever changing requirements :) Anyway I edited again, check it now.

Comment: Thanks again!  Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be doing anything.  I made sure to change 'page1' to 'login' per my example URLs.  Any idea clue why it wouldn't be working?  I appreciate your generous help!

Comment: On second thought, the only thing I think that would cause this to not work is the fact that my urls have a '/' between the directory and the start of the query string.  Could this be the cause?

Comment: I have posted it after properly testing the code. Can you post your complete .htaccess here and the URI that is not working. My code will work with both `/page1?action=signup&var2=dynamicVar` and `/page1/?action=signup&var2=dynamicVar`

Comment: Sorry I never got back to you on this.  This worked great!  Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^page1(.*)$ /page2$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Input

```
http://mysite.com/page1?action=signup&var2=dynamicVar
```

this is the rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^page1?(.*)$ /?$1 [L,R=301]
```

redirect to

```
http://mysite.com/?action=signup&var2=dynamicVar
```

this will redirect all request o page1 with get parameters to http://mysite.com

Answer (score -1):

Use %{REQUEST_URI}
fi.:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

rewrites anything that starts with "website" to "www.website..." including the querystring (by use of %{REQUEST_URI})